# ImageView images animation app crushes on start [SWIFT]

Tags: ios, swift, exception, uiimageview

i am trying to make these images to animate, but simulator keeps crushing on start, could someone please advise - what am i doing wrong? 
Here is what my ViewController.swift looks like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var imagesListArray: [UIImage] = []
        for name in ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg", "img4.jpg"] {
            if let image = UIImage(named: name) {
                imagesListArray.append(image)
            }
        }
        ImageView.animationImages = imagesListArray;
        ImageView.animationDuration = 5
        ImageView.startAnimating()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

I surely have there images imported (although this wouldn't be the problem even if i didn't). So, what else could that be?

Here I will add the exception log that i am getting on start:

```
2015-10-21 15:05:47.168 singleVshow[11922:7207193] -[UIView setAnimationImages:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa119531770
2015-10-21 15:05:47.172 singleVshow[11922:7207193] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[UIView setAnimationImages:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa119531770'

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I will add the call stack if necessary.

Comment: The imageListArray is correct, but your ImageView is nil. Check if it is correctly connected. Check if the dot next to the outlet is filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that it's a UIView object that's trying to call `setAnimationImages`. You may want to verify that the outlet to your UIImageView in your storyboard is set correctly.  You may just want to completely delete the outlet and recreate it for good measure, making sure the UIImageView is selected.

Comment: Wow! At first i thought it is "Have You Tried Turning It Off And On Again" kind of answer, but man, was I surprised when it actually worked, lol. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArseniyS.Ivanov You're welcome! I've learned the hard way that outlets and actions in Interface Builder can get mucked up pretty easily if you're not too careful.

Answer (score 0):

Use this peace of code instead of yours

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var imagesListArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    for name in ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg", "img4.jpg"] {
        if let image = UIImage(named: name) {
            imagesListArray.add(image)
        }
    }
    ImageView.animationImages = imagesListArray;
    ImageView.animationDuration = 5
    ImageView.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This code gives me two issues as follows:

First: Value of type 'NSMutableArray' has no member 'add'.
Second: Cannot assign a value of type 'NSMutableArray' to a value of type '[UIImage]'

Comment: sorry about that, i accidentally hit enter while writing last comment, edited it now.